# Case Insensitive Regex expression for getting file

Tags: kettle, pdi

I have a scenario where i am taking files from a folder for data loading which is having naming convention as .*Customer_.*.txt.But also i would like to make this expression case insensitive so if any file named CUSTOMER_1234 comes.It will also accept that and process accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex:

```
(?i)customer(?-i).*\.txt
```

in the wildcard section of the "get files" steps or any other regex step you are using. This will filter out files starting with either "customer" or "CUSTOMER".

Attached a sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/a97e91e34f2127043856).

Hope this helps :)

Sample Screenshot:

[image]

---

**Modifying my previous answer based on the comment below:**

If you are looking to match the pattern "customer_" irrespective of case sensitivity, first of all you can easily do it using a Javascript **"match"** function. You just need to pass the file names in upper case and match with the uppercase pattern. This will easily fetch you the result. Check the JS snip below:

```
var pattern="customer_"; //pattern is the word pattern you want to match

var match_files= upper(files).match(upper(pattern)); // files in the list of files you are getting from the directory

if(upper(match_files)==upper(pattern)){
      //set one flag as 'match'
}
else{
     // set the flag as 'not match'
}
```

But in case you need to use regex expression only. Then you can try the below regex:

```
.*(?i)(customer|CUSTOMER).*(?-i)\.txt
```

This would work for "_123_Customer_1vasd.txt" patterns too.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi rishu this is fine..But in case of any file coming as 12346_customer_gdhdhdjdjd.txt..in this case itc wont work..i want the file having name customer_ as case insensitive,,please respond if u know

Comment: @DebayanBhattacharjya check the modified answer above.